# Elasticsearch as a cache, rebuild index vs update in place?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch as a cache/search index for products in an e-commerce catalog. Certain events (including but not limited to bulk product updates) can cause all or a significant portion of documents to require re-indexing. I figure I have 2 options:

**Option A:** Update the affected documents in place.

**Option B:** Create a new index, continue to use the old one to serve queries until the new one is fully built, then point the app to the new index.

My questions about these approaches:

1. Is option A likely to be more disruptive to "live" queries when the updates are in progress than option B, even though both indexes in option B live in the same cluster and therefore share physical resources such as RAM and CPU?
2. If yes, is there a reasonable rule of thumb to follow here, such as "use option A if less than x% of documents need updating, otherwise use option B"?

I imagine other factors such as the size of the index and how long it takes to rebuild come into play too, but I'm actually dealing with many independent product catalogs/indexes that vary in size from under 1000 documents to over a million, so my goal is to come up with a general strategy that's likely to work reasonably well for everyone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question but IMO not trivial to answer.

Why would you want to create a new index? To skip the merge of replaced documents (since there is no in-place update in Elasticsearch because Lucene writes data immutably).

Why might you want not to create a new index? Because an update query might be much smaller; use a script to set / change a value in a million documents is much smaller on the network than resending a million documents.

Your choice will probably also depend on your bottleneck. Is it network, CPU / RAM, or disk? For example with option B you wouldn't have to wait for a merge to happen to reclaim your disk space, but could trigger that right after you create the new index.

I don't think there are any benchmarks for this specific scenario, but my gut feeling is that I would only think about recreating with

- 10K or even 100K documents
- hitting at least 1/3 of the documents (could also be 1/2 — it's really just a guess).

Comment: Your gut feeling (down to the specific numbers) is remarkably similar to what I've been working toward, so this is a great sanity check.

Comment: To offer a little more perspective, the system in place now does option B exclusively, and I'm just considering making it better/smarter/more efficient by introducing option A. (Cache-expiring events are happening more frequently than anticipated.) My top concern is whether A may be more *disruptive* to "live" queries than B. Disk space is no concern, network not much, CPU/RAM more so.

Comment: If you're not concerned about the disk space you could [throttle the merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html) further to decrease its impact. There are multiple knobs you can turn and I'd just start with something and explore further as you hit pain points. IMO this will be hard to guess correctly.